# Chisel tools installation; Unable to fint scct

Tags: chisel, scct, riscv

I am trying to get started with Chisel. Following the instructions on Chisel web page, I installed scala 2.11 and sbt, copied the build.sbt and Hello World example. However, I am unable to run the example. I am getting following errors.

```
tariq@ubuntu:~/work/scala-test$ sbt run
[info] Set current project to scala-test (in build file:/home/tariq/work/scala-test/)
[info] Updating {file:/home/tariq/work/scala-test/}scala-test...
[info] Resolving com.github.scct#sbt-scct;0.2.1 ...
[warn] Host repo1.maven.org not found. url=https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/github/scct/sbt-scct_2.11_0.13/0.2.1/sbt-scct-0.2.1.pom
[info] You probably access the destination server through a proxy server that is not well configured.
[warn]  module not found: com.github.scct#sbt-scct;0.2.1
[warn] ==== local: tried

<snip>

info] Resolving jline#jline;2.12 ...
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: com.github.scct#sbt-scct;0.2.1: not found
[warn]  :: edu.berkeley.cs#chisel_2.11;latest.release: not found
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn] 
[warn]  Note: Some unresolved dependencies have extra attributes.  Check that these dependencies exist with the requested attributes.
[warn]      com.github.scct:sbt-scct:0.2.1 (sbtVersion=0.13, scalaVersion=2.11)

<snip>

    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[error] (*:update) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: com.github.scct#sbt-scct;0.2.1: not found
[error] unresolved dependency: edu.berkeley.cs#chisel_2.11;latest.release: not found
[error] Total time: 23 s, completed Nov 19, 2014 4:26:38 PM
```

Answer (score 1):

It appears sbt can't reach the internet (4th [info] line refers to this). 
sbt needs to be able to reach the internet in order to download packages.

Are you behind a proxy? Are you running this in a VM?

Comment: Yes, I am running in a VM.

Comment: Then you will need to allow the VM to reach the internet in order to get these packages. If you are worried about security, you can do this only temporary, and once chisel completes its first run you can disable network access.

Comment: Actually, I am not blocking internet on the VM.  I can ping github and berkeley.edu

Comment: Can you ping repo1.maven.org (the host it is trying to connect to)? Are all ports open? It is using https.

Comment: `tariq@ubuntu:~$ ping repo1.maven.org
PING sonatype.map.fastly.net (199.27.79.209) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 199.27.79.209: icmp_seq=1 ttl=128 time=48.2 ms
64 bytes from 199.27.79.209: icmp_seq=2 ttl=128 time=140 ms
64 bytes from 199.27.79.209: icmp_seq=3 ttl=128 time=110 ms
64 bytes from 199.27.79.209: icmp_seq=4 ttl=128 time=100 ms
^C`

Comment: Seems to be reachable